# Category and Singleton Tutorials

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, singleton, categories

I've heared about singletons and categorys throughout my search for a way to pass data from one view and back using a navigation controller.

Ive also found the segue method but that's just a one-way

So my question is:
Are there any good tutorials or a capital in a book that can teach me the basics and maybe advanced techniques of categorys and singletons? Like what it is / how it works / neat stuff to do with it.

Couldn't find anything anywhere I'm afraid. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022). Great coverage of categories, singletons, and many more topics.

Comment: Is it a huge problem that it is from 2009? What I mean is: is there a lot of outdated stuff in there?

Comment: Nope. There's some stuff (like 10-15%) that's more applicable to OS X than to iOS, and there may be a topic or two that they'd add if they updated the book, but I wouldn't say anything is outdated.

Comment: one of the main things @JohnRW interested in is singletons, and that book has an outdated implementation (it doesnt use dispatch_once). its a good book for concepts, but double check the implementations